# How can I read duplicate grades from csv and then sort by grade point average and each person's name?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

The following function reads the name of each person along with their grade point average from a CSV file. If the grades are not duplicates, it displays them in ascending order; otherwise, it sorts and displays them alphabetically.

Example :

```
hossein: 16
linda: 7.5
mandana: 7.5
```

####################################

csv file:

```
mandana,5,7,3,15
hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
linda,5,7,3,15
sara,0,5,20,14
soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali,1,9
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
ahmad,1,9
```

my code:

```
from statistics import mean
import csv
import operator
def sss(): 
    with open('alaki.csv','r') as s:
        sp = csv.reader(s)
        res = {}
        for lines in sp:
            name = lines[0]
            ssd = mean([float(l) for l in lines[1:]])
            res[name] = ssd
        m = len(res.values())
        m2 = len(set(res.values()))
    if m == m2:
        soe = dict(sorted(res.items() , key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
        for i,v in soe.items():
            print(i,v)

    else:
        soes = dict(sorted(res.items() , key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1])))
        for s,d in soes.items():
            print(s,d)
sss()
```

Correct output:

```
ahmad,5.0
ali,5.0
hamid,6.066666666666666
linda, 7.5
mandana, 7.5
soheila,7.833333333333333
sara,9.75
sina,11.285714285714286
sarvin,11.375
```

Please help me write the program so that its output is like the output above

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where your problem is. I ran this and it appears to list averages in order. Can you provide your expected output and the error or what you are getting?

Comment: Use `key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])`. This will give the required output whether there are duplicate scores or not.

Comment: I edited my question, please read it and I will be happy to help me

Comment: It is easier if you don't use a dictionary and simply sort tuples of the form `(average, name)` They will naturally sort by value, then name.  You can create your tuples list with: `tuples_list = ((mean(map(float,grades)),name) for name,*grades in csv.reader(open("alaki.csv","rt")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of the problem and your code suggests that you want to sort differently based on whether there are duplicate scores, but based on your sample output it looks like you simply want to sort the `grade, name` tuples the same way in all cases:

```
from statistics import mean
import csv


def sss() -> None:
    with open('alaki.csv', 'r') as s:
        for grade, name in sorted(
            (mean(float(l) for l in line[1:]), line[0])
            for line in csv.reader(s)
        ):
            print(f"{name},{grade}")


sss()
```

produces:

```
ahmad,5.0
ali,5.0
hamid,6.066666666666666
linda,7.5
mandana,7.5
soheila,7.833333333333333
sara,9.75
sina,11.285714285714286
sarvin,11.375
```

Comment: Your answer is both wrong and I do not want the output.Please look at the output I said in the question. Thanks

Comment: So you just want them sorted alphabetically in all cases?  That actually makes it much easier.  Why did you even mention the thing about treating duplicates differently if you don't want to sort things differently in that case?

Comment: I apologize to you